# email verification on laravel 7

Tags: laravel, mailtrap

I have a question, actually, I'm developing a web site using laravel 7 and I successfully make an email verification and password reset functionality using mailtrap.io; but all theses just in localhost, I'm wondering if there is any other way to use it in the production side because I want users to receive the email verification and password reset response on them's email not on mailtrap website.
here is an image shows the email verification and password reset response
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJQ4R.png)

Comment: Yes, you just need to change (and set up) the mail driver. There are a number of options. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#driver-prerequisites

Answer (score 0):

You can use sendgrid.com for mail delivery.
Make sure you configure DNS correctly before using it and configure the White Label correctly for you Domain.

.env

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=apikey
MAIL_PASSWORD=your_api_key_here
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=no-reply@yourdomain.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Comment: thank you for your help,
I found a good solution because I don't want to pay so I linked my project with my Gmail so it is cheaper.

Comment: Sendgrid offer 12000 mails monthly quota for free delivery.